# Qwt for Qt: How to connect to signal with new signal/slot flavour?

Tags: qt, syntax, signals, qwt, slot

I want to to connect to legend-label SIGNAL checked. With Qts old Signal/Slot-Syntax all is perfect, but i want to use the new connection to enable compile-time check? Any idea on how to connect it via new Signal/Slot-Syntax?

This is my code:

```
connect( m_plotLegend, SIGNAL( checked( const QVariant &, bool, int ) ), SLOT(legendChecked( const QVariant &, bool ) ) );
//connect(m_plotLegend, &QwtLegend::checked, this, &MeasurePlot::legendChecked);
```

With oldy syntax all is fine, with the new syntax the slot is never reached. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you check the return value of the `connect()` function call?

Comment: Yes. No success. The error message:  QObject::connect: signal not found in QwtLegend

Comment: Whatever your problem is - it should be unrelated to Qwt. The message comes from QObject::connectImpl in qobject.cpp and when using your debugger you should be able to find out why the senderMetaObject is a nullptr in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connect should work.

I test this with your Examplecode and it works fine:

Definition:

```
...
private slots:
void test(const QVariant &, bool);

signals:
void checked( const QVariant &, bool, int );
...
```

Connection:

```
...
connect(this, &TestClass::checked, this,  &TestClass::test);

emit checked(QVariant(QString("test")), true, 1);
...
```

Slot:

```
void TestClass::test(const QVariant &, bool)
{
...
}
```

Hope that helps a little bit.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. Sure it works if you connect to a signal in the same class. But try Qwt, you will get the error message QObject::connect: signal not found in QwtLegend.

Answer (score 1):

It seems 5 years later, this is still the case. Old SIGNAL/SLOT syntax works for Qwt signal/slots but the new syntax does not. You will get "QObject::connect: signal not found in [Qwt ClassName]."

For reference, I'm currently using Qwt 6.1.2 and Qt 5.9.6.

Comment: Had this issue again while adding a new feature to our Qwt app. Since last post I've upgraded to Qwt 6.2.0, Qt 5.15.2.
This issue might be caused by the build process or the way the Qwt project configures itself.  See this forum post https://forum.qt.io/post/718506. Note that I built qwt from source, both 6.1.2 and 6.2.0.