# QwtPlotPicker signal not found

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I am trying to get a function called when a `QwtPlot` is clicked, however, connecting the signal to a function fails.

When I run this minimal example

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <cassert>
#include <qwt_picker_machine.h>
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_picker.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QwtPlot plot;
    QwtPlotPicker picker{plot.canvas()};
    picker.setStateMachine(new QwtPickerClickPointMachine);
    auto connection = QObject::connect(
        &picker,
        qOverload<const QPointF &>(&QwtPlotPicker::selected),
        [](const QPointF &point) { qDebug() << point.x() << point.y(); }
    );
    assert(connection);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this `QtWarningMsg` message in the console output

> QObject::connect: signal not found in QwtPlotPicker

and the assertion fails.

The [Qwt-documentation](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_picker.html) states that `void QwtPlotPicker::selected(const QPointF &pos)` exists and is a signal.
Why is it not found?

In contrast, this connection works fine:

```
auto connection = QObject::connect(
    &plot,
    &QwtPlot::windowTitleChanged,
    [](const QString &title) { qDebug() << title; }
);
assert(connection);
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010844/qwt-for-qt-how-to-connect-to-signal-with-new-signal-slot-flavour).

The problem is not related to `qOverload` or that `QwtPlotPicker::selected` is overloaded because

```
auto connection = QObject::connect(
    &picker,
    &QwtPlotPicker::activated,
    [](bool) { qDebug() << "activated"; }
);
```

has the same issue.

I'm using Qwt 6.1.3 and Qt 5.8.0-1 with MinGW gcc 5.3.0-1.

Comment: you mean qwt 6.1.3?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus Yes, sorry, fixed.